# How to get distinct result in Mongo DB?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I am using mongoDB 2.6.5. I have a books collection.

```
   > db.books.find() 

{ "_id" : "5476f8b5e4b04367d6c95010", "author" : "abc", "title" : "xyz", "isbnNo" : "9781887902991", "category" : "Computer" } 

{ "_id" : "5476fae0e4b0016adffd08e4", "author" : "bcd", "title" : "uvw", "isbnNo" : "9781887902991", "category" : "Computer" } 

{ "_id" : "5476fb7ce4b0016adffd08e5", "author" : "cde", "title" : "pqr", "isbnNo" : "9781887902991", "category" : "Biography" }
```

I want result as :

```
{ "_id" : "5476fae0e4b0016adffd08e4", "author" : "bcd", "title" : "uvw", "isbnNo" : "9781887902991", "category" : "Computer" } 

{ "_id" : "5476fb7ce4b0016adffd08e5", "author" : "cde", "title" : "pqr", "isbnNo" : "9781887902991", "category" : "Biography" }
```

I mean any one book from each category like “Group By Category” in mySQL.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the aggregate pipeline with the `$group` and `$project` operators.

- Group based on the category.
- Pick the values of the first record in each group.
- Project the record for each group.

The Code:

```
db.books.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":"$category",
         "author":{$first:"$author"},
         "title":{$first:"$title"},
         "isbnNo":{$first:"$isbnNo"},
         "category":{$first:"$category"}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"author":1,
           "title":1,"isbnNo":1,"category":1}}
])
```